# SELECT query fails silently, no output produced

Tags: php, mysql

First of all I need to tell that I'm newbie on PHP/mySQL...

I'm trying to write simple plugins using php. Here is my php function code :

```
function example() {    
    global $DB;     
    $examplesql = $DB['DB_Database']->query("SELECT tid, added
                                                 FROM table GROUP BY tid
                                                 ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 5");
    while ($row = $DB['DB_Database']->fetch_assoc($examplesql)) {
        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row['added']);  
        $torid = $row['tid'];
    }   
    eval("\$exampletemplate = \""
         . $DB['DB_Template']->LoadTemplate('exampletemplate')
         . "\";"); 
    return $example;
}
```

so when I create a template named as `exampletemplate` and insert into that template this;

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>$time</td>
    <td>$torid;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

it must show list of last 5 `tid` sorted by `added` but all I get is a white page. No database error, nothing. Just a white page.

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A white page means you have error_reporting turned off. PHP wants to tell you what your error is but you won't let it. Put the following line of code at the top of your file, or in your config file, to enable error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also make sure [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) is ON in your php.ini file.

Comment: Hello , I'm using completely encrypted script with ioncube.. So i can't make changes on config file

Comment: @user2608650 You need to `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to enable errors onscreen for debugging.

Comment: I did make a few changes in php file and getting something like that http://i.imgur.com/4GcAiCn.png

Answer (score 0):

1st: Do you set or declare the variables `$time` and `$torid`? Is there an assurance that it is set inside the while-loop? Where do `$TSUE` came/set from?

2nd: Use `echo $time;` in html under `<?php ?>` like:

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $time; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $torid; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

3rd: Where or how you call your function?

Comment: Script doesn't need echo.. Typing $anything is enough to call that value that you set in php file.. I don't know TSUE came from , this is encrypted script. i see that in a few decrypted files.

Comment: *Typing $anything is enough to call that value that you set in php file*? Are you saying that it will display the value of `$anything` without echo in HTML?

Comment: yes it is, but i didn't access this php file directly. For example i have a main page. I'm adding this php file and creating template in script's options it's calling Plugins for script.. And then i set Show this Plugins on main page it shows what i insert into template $anything . no need any echo. but as i said it must be called in mysql and setted on php file.

Comment: Ahhh.. I see, something like a MasterPage in asp.net webforms.